# Refactor Error Handler to Recursively retry failed api calls

Tags: javascript, api, recursion, closures

I need help organizing my code so I can recursively retry failed api requests. Here is an example of a function that makes an api call (I have multiple functions like this which make various api calls with a payload and they accept a callback function, within the promise the apiCall function mocks it):

```
function boilerPlateApiCall() {
  return new Promise(((resolve, reject) => {
    // make an api call
    apiCall('GET',(err, res) => {
      if (err) { return reject(err); }
      resolve(res);
    });
  }))
    .then(res => res.data)
    .catch(handleErrors(boilerPlateApiCall, []));
}
```

Here is my `handleErrors` function:

```
function handleErrors(recursiveFunc, parameters) {    
    const handleError = function handleError(err) {        
        console.log('Error in request: ', recursiveFunc.name);
        console.log('Error is ', err);
        console.log('handleErrors');
      if (err.code === 401) {
        console.log('authorizing and trying again');        
      }
  
      if (err.code === 404) {
        console.log('404');
        return Promise.resolve();
      }
      if (err.code === 403 || err.code === 503) {
        console.log('too many requests');            
          setTimeout(() => {
            recursiveFunc(...parameters);
          }, 1000);
        }
        return Promise.reject(err);
      }
    };
    return handleError;
  }
```

The `handleErrors` function is used in a `.catch` for all of the api methods. The main reason for `handleErrors` is for logging errors and to be able to get the function name where the error is thrown. However, based on the structure, in the if statement that checks for 403 and 503 status codes, this will run infinitely if the same codes are returned.

Because of the structure of this code (specifically, the catch function in `boilerPlateApiCall`, the handleErrors function is called whenever an error is hit. I can't figure out how to wrap the `setTimeout` recursive call in some type of closure to limit the amount of retries/attempts.

Ideally I want something like this, but because `boilerPlateApiCall` invokes handleErrors in the .catch, the closure is reset on every attempt:

```
function handleErrors(recursiveFunc, parameters) {  
    let numberOfRetries = 5;
    const handleError = function handleError(err) {        
        console.log('Error in request: ', recursiveFunc.name);
        console.log('Error is ', err);
        console.log('handleErrors');
      if (err.code === 401) {
        console.log('authorizing and trying again');        
      }
  
      if (err.code === 404) {
        console.log('404');
        return Promise.resolve();
      }
      if (err.code === 403 || err.code === 503) {
        console.log('too many requests');
        if(numberOfRetries > 0){         
         numberOfRetries--   
          setTimeout(() => {
            recursiveFunc(...parameters);
          }, 1000);
        }
       }
        return Promise.reject(err);
      }
    };
    return handleError;
  }
```

The only way I can think of doing this is to possibly pass each api call function (`boilerPlateApiCall`) a "retry" argument, and then pass a retry argument to `handleErrors`.

Comment: If you are in control of the api functions, then perhaps `boilerPlateApiCall (3 , ...moreArgs)` will call `handleError (3, boilerplateApiCall, moreArgs)`, which on failure will check if `numberOfRetries` (that first parameter) is positive.  If it is, then it will call `recursiveFunc (numberOfRetries - 1, ...moreArgs)`   If it's not, you proceed with the final error.  All this is predicated on your being able to change the API of `boilerPlateApiCall`.  If you can't do that, then I'd have to think more.

Comment: Thanks Scott. I have access to the api functions. I was thinking about this route but would prefer to not go this way since a lot of functions would need to be updated to receive the extra argument. I'm really stumped on this one and may have to go the route you suggested.